# Djoser Permission Classes Issue

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, customization, djoser

I am trying make an app with djoser as my third party package. I have made a bunch of `@api_views` along with it and i wanted to apply some permissions as well. I have already done `IsAuthenticated` but am unable to update custom permission for djoser:

```
'user': ['djoser.permissions.CurrentUserOrAdminOrReadOnly']
```

I have used PERMISSION instead of DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES in djoser list.

I would like to be able to get a token and only able to change that users data and not someone elses but till now it hasnt worked. i can update or post any type of data of different user  with a valid  token.

Can someone help me out here? Thanks in Advance

See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMzZl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you question is but if you want to specify global permission for Djoser views

WRONG

`DJOSER = {"DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": {"user": "permission"}}`

CORRECT

`DJOSER = {"PERMISSIONS": {"user": "permission"}}`

If that doesn't answer your question, remove image from your question and post actual code.